# What does 「うざいどす」 mean?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, dialects

Source: https://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/4685177829409008642/comment/kincity

> こういう語りをするやつがほんとに音楽業界全般見てるの？という疑問がいつもある。ジャズ寄り音楽家とかは毎晩ライブやって生きてたりするよね。CD3000枚でドヤるのも正直**うざいどす**。

[goo.ne](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%86%E3%81%96%E3%81%84/) defines 「うざい」as:

> ［形］《「うざったい」の省略形。「うぜえ」とも》あれこれとうるさい。わずらわしい。

〜どす is another way of saying 〜です in 京都弁 according to [goo.ne](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/dialect/2042/m0u/)

Why did the commentor use うざい here? Or perhaps うざい has a nuance meaning of 多い here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ウザい is a slangy adjective meaning "annoying", "irritating", "gets on my nerves", etc. It does not mean 多い.

どす is a feminine Kyoto-ben variant of です. I think he used it not because he is a Kyotoite but because he wanted to make this sound milder by using a funny sentence ending (どす may be [associated with sarcasm](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69455/5010), too).

> CD3000枚でドヤるのも正直うざいどす
>
> Also, TBH having (only) 3,000 CDs and bragging about it is annoying to me.

This person is saying having 3,000 CDs is not special nor important.